# Could someone explain how this estimate number is being arrived at?

Tags: sampling

I'm reading **hands on machine learning with SciKit-Learn and TensorFlow** by Aurélien Géron and came across this passage on page 51:

> For example, the US population is composed of 51.3% female and 48.7%
>   male, so a well-conducted survey in the US would try to maintain this
>   ratio in the sample: 513 female and 487 male. This is called stratified sampling: the population is divided into homogeneous subgroups
>   called strata, and the right number of instances is sampled from each
>   stratum to guarantee that the test set is representative of the
>   overall population. If they used purely random sampling, there would
>   be about 12% chance of sampling a skewed test set with either less
>   than 49% female or more than 54% female.

It is not at all clear to me, how the **12%** figure quoted above, is calculated. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4):

Make a few approximations: 1) US population is large enough that we are sampling with replacement, and 2) that n=1000 binomial is large enough to be Gaussian with mean=np and variance=np(1-p).

Here, $n = 1000$, $p = 0.513$. So, 1 standard deviation $= 15.8$.

49% = -1.45z and 54% = 1.7z

$P$(sampling outside of -1.45 to 1.7$)$ = $1-P$(sampling inside) =

$1 - (\Phi(1.7) - \Phi(-1.45)) =\\ 1 - (0.9554 - 0.0808) =\\ 0.1254%$

Or you can do away with approximation 2) and do a bunch of summations with the binomial distribution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this line: 49% = -1.45z and 54% = 1.7z
Why do authors choose 49% and 54% boundaries?
How do you arrive at coefficients to scale z-score?